# Binary Search Tree Updating

Tags: binary-search-tree, avl-tree

How can I update values in Binary Search Tree without affecting its properties (all the nodes in the left subtree have values that are less than the value of the root node and all the nodes of the right subtree have values that are greater than the value of the root node).

I tried deleting and inserting the new Value, but It's an assignment and my teacher wants different solution using rotations or swaps.

Comment: Deleting the old value and inserting the new seems reasonable, because of the potential that the new value will need to be in a different subtree.

Comment: The BST represents an ordering of values - not an ordering of nodes.  If a value stored at a node changes then deleting that node and inserting a new one with the 'update' is a reasonable approach.

Comment: @trincot I want a solution with AVL techniques.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Which techniques?

Comment: @trincot left and right rotations

Comment: OK, but these rotations don't change the inorder sequence of the node's values. How does that relate to *updating* a node value? I mean when a node is just updated *inplace*, the tree's inorder sequence can be disturbed (invalid BST). AVL rotations are not going to resolve that, because they are designed to not change anything to the inorder sequence. If it was wrong before a rotation, it will still be wrong after a rotation.

Comment: the idea is to update the value of a node , and if this new value affected BST properties we should change its position with rotations  (this is what he told us to do but personaly  I find it more sensible to use delete & insert  )

Comment: Like I wrote above, that procedure cannot work: applying AVL rotations cannot fix an invalid BST. AVL rotations are *specifically* designed for valid BSTs. It you apply them on an invalid BST, the BST will remain invalid. It cannot be fixed with the standard left/right AVL rotations. Either you have misunderstood the assignment, or your teacher doesn't know what they are talking about. I think the first option is more likely.

Comment: I totally agree with you ,using AVL rotations makes no sense . I toled him that but he consists not to use delete and insert , Is there any other ways to solve this ?